# How to generate JSON from a database result?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert data from a mysql table into json. The key value in the result is the value of a fieldname.

Data:

```
hostname, status, assetid, environment, email, appname
hostA, active, 1234, production, test@gmail.com, appA
hostB, retired, 23432, production, test@gmail.com, appB
hostC, active, 1231, development, test@gmail.com, AppC
hostC, active, 1231, development, test1@gmail.com, AppD
```

This is the table structure

```
create table assets (
hostname varchar(128),
status varchar(16),
assetid varchar(16),
environment varchar(32),
appname varchar(16),
email varchar(16)
)
```

Required output

```json
{
 "hostA": {
  "status" : "active",
  "assetid" : "123",
  "environment" : "production",
  "app" : "appA",
  "email" : ["test@gmail.com"]
 },
 "hostB": {
  "status" : "retired",
  "assetid" : "23432",
  "environment" : "production",
  "app" : "appB",
  "email" : ["test@gmail.com"]
 },
 "hostC": {
  "status" : "active",
  "assetid" : "1231",
  "environment" : "development",
  "app" : "appC, appD",
  "email" : ["test@gmail.com","test1@gmail.com"]
 }
}
```

What I have this. Read through some examples online, not sure how to proceed.

```
for row in rows:
    hostname = row[field_map['HOSTNAME']
    status = row[field_map['STATUS']]
    assetid = row[field_map['ASSETID']]
    environment = row[field_map['ENV']]
    appname = row[field_map['APPNAME']]
    email = row[field_map['EMAIL']]

    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    # if the hostname already exists then add this appname to the appname list
    # if the hostname already exists and this email address is not there, add 
    # this email address to the list
    if ??
        d[hostname]['status'] = status
        d[hostname]['assetid'] = assetid
        d[hostname]['environment'] = environment
        d[hostname]['appname'] = [appname]
        d[hostname]['email'] = [email]
    else
        d[hostname]['appname'].append(appname)
        d[hostname]['email'].append(email)
```

Comment: What exactly is the data-structure that holds the mysql table data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dictionary outside the row loop that you'd be adding each hostname into. For demonstration, let's call it `result`

```
result = {}
for row in rows:
    hostname = row[field_map['HOSTNAME']]

    if hostname in result:
       d = result[hostname]
       # append to appname and email here
    else:
       d = collections.OrderedDict()
       # prepare single element appname and email lists here

    # set rest of variables here to override existing hosts
    d['status'] = status

    result[hostname] = d
print(result)
```

Note that your example has `app` (not `appname`) as a comma-separated string while `email` is an actual list

Answer (score 0):

If your data saved in a csv file `data.csv`, you can do it this way:

```py
import json
import csv
json_data = [json.dumps(d) for d in csv.DictReader(open('data.csv'),skipinitialspace=True)]
```

`json_data` will be the required json:

````json
{"hostname": "hostA", "status": "active", "assetid": "1234", "environment": "production", "email": "test@gmail.com", "appname": "appA"}', 
'{"hostname": "hostB", "status": "retired", "assetid": "23432", "environment": "production", "email": "test@gmail.com", "appname": "appB"}', 
'{"hostname": "hostC", "status": "active", "assetid": "1231", "environment": "development", "email": "test@gmail.com", "appname": "AppC"}', 
'{"hostname": "hostC", "status": "active", "assetid": "1231", "environment": "development", "email": "test1@gmail.com", "appname": "AppD"}```
````